# Creating a UI Button for a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am very new to Swift and Xcode. I am trying to make a UIButton appear at the right side of a tableView cell once the user presses the return key. Right now I am just having problems having a button appear in general.

From my understanding here is my custom class TextInputTableViewCell which I believe should create a button:

```
class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
var cellButton: UIButton!

func createCellButton()
{
    let image = UIImage(named: "Completed Circle.png")
    cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 340, y: 56, width: 30, height: 30));
    cellButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
    addSubview(cellButton)
}
```

And then here is where I configure the properties of the cell in my ViewController class:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! TextInputTableViewCell
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear //to get background image loaded
    cell.createCellButton()



    return cell
}
```

I know I am probably messing something up. Also, any tips on how to make the appear after the user presses enter would be appreciated. I have the textFieldShouldReturn function set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do not you use storyboard to make a `UIButton` and make an Outlet. Then in `cellForRowAt` do `cell.button.isHidden = true` `cell.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` (or something similar, not sure about actual spelling). Then make your `TextInputTableViewCell` conform `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate { ..
```

inside cell:

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
     self.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     self.button.isHidden = false
     return true
 }
```

you might face some problems with reusability of cells, so better make some local variable like `var userDidEnterText = false` to check if user has changed something

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn does not respond to return key when in TextInputTableViewCell class. But it does in the ViewController class. However in this class, it compile errors come up when trying to refer to "self.cellButton..."

Comment: ops. did not notice, try to change `cell.textField.delegate = self` to `cell.textField.delegate = cell`

Comment: Works great now! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: do not forget to accept, will help some one in future :) and if you have some questions about reusability, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the `createCellButton()` body I can tell that the value of `x` & `y` could be the source of the problem. I think that the button is created out of the cell frame. Try to use the following parameters:

```
cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30));
```